# How to use Google Guice SPI?

Tags: java, maven, guice, spi

I have a GuiceService class with injector creating and getBean method in API class, but after move my project to maven all Guice Modules have been in IMPL module. How I might to get guice modules from impl jar by Google Guice SPI to create injector? It has a few documenation and no examples..

Please do not recommend Java SPI and reflection. I need Guice SPI.